# Remove a folder from github which does not show locally

Tags: python, macos, github, jupyter-notebook, github-for-mac

I uploaded a Jupyter notebook on github, since then I worked on it locally and then committed the changes. Now I have a `.ipynb_checkpoints` folder which does not appear on the local repo, and I would like to remove it from the online repo. If I check with git status, or if I try to commit, it says that everything is up-to-date. How can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

For this very case I simply deleted the folder on local, committed the changes, and then added back the files as I wanted them to be. By the way I would love to know a more general solution, to use when the number of files or folders is too high to handle them individually.

Answer (score 0):

To delete a file from github already deleted in your local repo, here are a couple of things that you can try:

```
git add . -a
git commit -m 'removing deleted files'
git push origin master
```

From the user manual 'The commit -a will update the index with any files that you’ve modified or removed and create a commit, all in one step.'

If this doesn’t work, you may need to delete the history from .git using e.g.

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch 
<files to remove>' HEAD
```

then

```
git commit -m ‘deleting file’
git push origin master --force
```